# Se puede evitar mostrar una fila en caso de que haya un campo vacío o uno lleno? Con MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

necesito saber como se puede hacer una consulta en la que si falta un campo de una fila por rellenar o de manera contraria si hay un campo lleno en esa fila entonces como evitar que se muestre esa fila si hay varios campos:

ejemplo:tabla persona

tengo un la fila con los campos asi

AI------->*idpersona *idnombre * idprestamo

```
            1          1           1
            2          2          null
```

como puedo hacer para evitar mostrar toda la segunda fila del campo idprestamo si esta en null  o del caso contrario como evitar mostrar si hay un numero en el campo idprestamo de la primera fila... se puede hacer? alguna solución? stackovers Por su atencion Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la última linea de la consulta preguntas si idprestamo es like una variable junto con is nulo, o es parecido a la variable o es nulo, pero las dos cosas sin separador lógico no van a funcionar. Creo que por ahí puede andar el problema.
Si no quieres que muestre nulo tendría que ser:

```
... And mi campo is not null
```

Comment: exacto ahí es donde no se como añadir el is null :( ? y por que digamos al final de la linea yo lo tengo asi, EJ: pr.idprestamo LIKE '".$q."%' is null; y con el distinct que tengo al principio no me debe de mostrar la fila con los campos idprestamo que esten en Null, alguna sugerencia? @Carmen

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Carmen ya lo solucione tenias razon con la parte de los operadores. :)

Answer (score 3):

Al definir la tabla cada campo tiene un valor por defecto que tú decides o bien permites que sea nulo, solo tienes que preguntar si el valor del campo por el quieres filtrar es distinto del valor por defecto o del valor que eliges como condición. Por ejemplo:

SELECT * FROM MITABLA WHERE MICAMPO IS NOT NULL;

Son consultas sencillas, deberías intentar hacerlas y si tienes problemas poner consultas concretas de código. Lo que preguntas es demasiado genérico.

Comment: Gracias @Carmen ya lo habia resuelto jeje ahora solo tengo un problema en como implementarlo a un buscador que tengo

Answer (score 0):

Este el el codigo de mi consulta que mostrara el buscador, donde esta pr.idprestamo ahi es donde digo que sea null pero me sigue mostrando resultados multiplicados que hay en mi base :/ Lo estare metiendo mal :(??   @Carmen

$sql="select distinct df.idficha, ml.clas, ml.titulo, ml.autor, ml.editorial, ml.fecha, ml.asignatura, ml.isbn, cc.categoria, ca.carrera, cu.cuatrimestre, cp.plantel, mp.periodico, mr.revistas,pr.idprestamo
   from  dficha ta

LEFT JOIN dficha df ON ta.idficha=df.idficha
   LEFT JOIN mlibro ml ON ta.idlibro=ml.idlibro
   LEFT JOIN ccategoria cc ON ta.idcategoria=cc.idcategoria
   LEFT JOIN ccarrera ca ON ta.idcarrera=ca.idcarrera
   LEFT JOIN ccuatrimestre cu ON ta.idcuatrimestre=cu.idcuatrimestre
   LEFT JOIN cplantel cp ON ta.idplantel=cp.idplantel
   LEFT JOIN mperiodico mp ON ta.idperiodico=mp.idperiodico
   LEFT JOIN mrevistas mr ON ta.idrevistas=mr.idrevistas
   LEFT JOIN dprestamo pr ON ta.idprestamo=pr.idprestamo

WHERE titulo LIKE '".$q."%'  OR autor LIKE '".$q."%' OR editorial LIKE '".$q."%' OR asignatura LIKE '".$q."%' OR pr.idprestamo LIKE '".$q."%' is null  LIMIT 0 , 15";

Comment: Kevin is null no va con like sino con =, no es semejante a sino igual a. En este caso el is sería equivalente al igual, es decir, actúa como operador.

Comment: No sé si quieres hacer esta consulta: .......WHERE titulo LIKE '".$q."%' OR autor LIKE '".$q."%' OR editorial LIKE '".$q."%' OR asignatura LIKE '".$q."%' OR pr.idprestamo is null LIMIT 0 , 15"; ...... o esta otra: ......WHERE titulo LIKE '".$q."%' OR autor LIKE '".$q."%' OR editorial LIKE '".$q."%' OR asignatura LIKE '".$q."%' OR pr.idprestamo LIKE '".$q."%' OR pr.idprestamo is null LIMIT 0 , 15";.... Creo que lo que quieres es la primera, pero ten en cuenta que el operador "OR" hace que se cumpla una u otra condición, si que el campo sea null siempre debe cumplirse tendría que ser "AND".